# Drop all rows in all columns in pandas dataframe if the value in the column row is zero

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop all rows that are zero in the "feet" column.

```
df['feet'] = df['feet'][(df != 0).all(1)]


dataset.info()
```

the above code gives such a result:

```
col1 8640 non-value object
col2 8640 non-value object
col3 8640 non-value object
col4 8640 non-value object
feet 7640 non-value object
```

As you can see, the code correctly remove the values ​​in the 'feet' column, but I also want it to delete the rows in all columns where 'feet' = 0

I can do it easily with Numpy but I want to know how it can be done without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['feet'] != 0]
```

Or [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df.query("feet != 0")
```

Comment: This is not the point. I want to delete all rows in all columns but only those with zeros in the 'feet' column

Comment: @tbone - Sorry, answer was changed.

Comment: @ansev - Interesting, I check time of edit and your time of answer and your was one minute later... Not sure why

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
df[df['feet'].ne(0)]
```

or

```
df[df['feet'] != 0]
```

or

```
df[~(df['feet'] == 0)]
```

---

```
df[~(df['feet'].eq(0))]
```